# Link button will not work with JQuery modal form

Tags: c#, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have a JQuery modal form with 4 image buttons.  When the modal box opens and I click on those buttons then nothing happens.  I know that when the box opens it moves outside of the form but I do not know how to get it back.  I have tried several variations on the .parent().appendTo($("form")); and have changed that in many different ways with no success.  Currently when I use that the box opens up but the entire screen is darkened and I cannot click on the buttons.  Here is my JQuery function:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#Change").dialog({
            resizable: false,
            draggable: false,
            width: 800,
            modal: true,
            show: { effect: 'fadeIn', duration: 500 },
            hide: { effect: 'fadeOut', duration: 300 },
            autoOpen: false,
            open: function (type, data) {
                $(this).parent().appendTo($("form"));
            }
        });

        $("#ui-dialog-title-dialog").hide();
        $(".ui-dialog-titlebar").removeClass('ui-widget-header');

        $("#openChange1").click(function () {
            $("#<%=txtCardChange.ClientID %>").val("1");
            $("#Change").dialog("open");
            $('.ui-widget-overlay').live("click", function () {
                $("#Change").dialog("close");

            });
            return false;
        });

    });
</script>
```

If needed here is my html to call the modal form:

```
<a id="openChange1" href="#" style="color: Red">Change Card</a>
```

The html for the modal form is just inside a simple div tag:

```
        <div id="Change">
            \\html here
        </div>
```

So, any help would be greatly appreciated.  If needed I am using Visual Studio 2012 with .NET 4.0.  The code behind the buttons are in C#.  Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned, JQuery moves the contents of the dialog to a direct child of the page body to solve several rendering issues: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/preventing-dialog-from-rearranging-dom-flow

The problem is that if you move the buttons immediately back, the 'overlay' div that is used to darken the rest of the screen and make the dialog modal (ie eat click events) prevents your button clicks from happening in the original location.

One solution is to use a clone of your Change div for the modal and bind click handlers that call click() on the original buttons.

Another option is to have the buttons call .NET's postback methods instead of letting the normal HTML form do the submit:

```
__doPostBack("ctl00$button_name_here");
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem I solved as below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#Change").dialog({
            resizable: false,
            draggable: false,
            width: 800,
            modal: true,
            show: { effect: 'fadeIn', duration: 500 },
            hide: { effect: 'fadeOut', duration: 300 },
            autoOpen: false,
            appendTo: "form"
        });

        $("#ui-dialog-title-dialog").hide();
        $(".ui-dialog-titlebar").removeClass('ui-widget-header');

        $("#openChange1").click(function () {
            $("#<%=txtCardChange.ClientID %>").val("1");
            $("#Change").dialog("open");
            $('.ui-widget-overlay').live("click", function () {
                $("#Change").dialog("close");

            });
            return false;
        });

    });
</script>
```

In jQuery UI v1.10 they added an appendTo property, which seems to do the same thing as calling .parent().appendTo($("form")). The dialog appears on top of the grayed background. And Post back does work.

Answer (score 1):

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" id="openChange1" onclientclick="openChange1Click()" />

<script type="text/javascript">
function openChange1Click () {
        $("#<%=txtCardChange.ClientID %>").val("1");
        $("#Change").dialog("open");
        $('.ui-widget-overlay').live("click", function () {
            $("#Change").dialog("close");

        });
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it, thanks for the help, it steered me in the right direction.

```
    $(function () {
        $("#Change").dialog({
            resizable: false,
            draggable: false,
            width: 400,
            modal: true,
            show: { effect: 'fadeIn', duration: 500 },
            hide: { effect: 'fadeOut', duration: 500 },
            autoOpen: false,
            open: function (type, data) {
                $(this).parent().appendTo("form:first");
            }
        }).parent().css('z-index', '1005');

        $("#ui-dialog-title-dialog").hide();
        $(".ui-dialog-titlebar").removeClass('ui-widget-header');
        $("#Change").hide().show();

        $("#openChange1").click(function () {
            $("#<%=txtCardChange.ClientID %>").val("1");
            $("#Change").dialog("open");
            $('.ui-widget-overlay').live("click", function () {
                $("#Change").dialog("close");
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
```